# How did Captain America survive freezing?

Tags: avengers, marvel, captain-america

At the end of [*Captain America: The First Avenger*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%3a_The_First_Avenger), Steve Rogers crashes  in the Arctic and is frozen there. He is rescued 70 years later and brought back to life.

Since [cryonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryonics) is not currently possible, is there an in-universe explanation on how he survived freezing? Was it that cryonics is possible in the Avenger universe or there is something related to Captain America's super-soldier status?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This harks back the The Avengers #4 (March 1964) where Captain America is defrosted, and they presume that he only survives due to the super-soldier serum from Project Rebirth.

The answer then is: He's a super-soldier.

Comment: You should've ended with "The answer then is: He's just cool like that" :)

Comment: "I'm Batman!" -- It's the answer to everything.

Comment: @BBlake - you also need to add the certain growl of Christian Bale... "imBATmun".

Comment: It is mentioned in the film that his cells have a protective regenerative ability due to the effects of the serum. It was in the bar when he was lamenting that he can't get drunk. I think this was also a subtle bit of foreshadowing that explained his ability to survive the freezing.